# How to create hyperlink in fo:block-container and fo:table?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I use xslt to build PDF from XML. In pdf-file I need to create hyperlinks in some areas like entire table or some area (block-container with background color). I tried to use <fo:basic-link external-destination="http://...">, but have no success. It works for text, but not for block-container and table. If someone knows how to do it, please help. I use Saxon and Apache FOP, just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fo:basic-link` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_basic-link) is your only option for making links.  As you have found, `fo:basic-link` is an 'inline' FO.  See the classifications of `%block;` and `%inline;` FOs at https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#d0e6532

However, `fo:basic-link` is defined to allow `%block;` content, so you should be able to put an `fo:table` inside an `fo:basic-link`. I.e., use nesting like:

```
fo:block
  fo:basic-link
    fo:table
```

If that doesn't work, however, you could put your `fo:table` inside an `fo:inline-container`, since that's an 'inline' FO and also allowed inside `fo:basic-link`.  You'd end up with a nesting structure like:

```
fo:block
  fo:basic-link
    fo:inline-container
      fo:table
```

Whether your formatter will do the right thing is a different question, but both ways should work.

Comment: Thank you @TonyGraham for your answer. Your first recommendation I tried before, didn't work. Now I'm trying the second one using "fo:inline-container".  When I applied this solution to my table, it fully went to the next page. Table has hyperlink. So, it worked partially. I didn't use "keep-together" for my table. May be need to play with this.
Also applied to the page with block-container with absolute position (3 vertical blocks). Didn't work. Later I upload images what I expected and what I have if this site allowes.

Comment: `fo:inline-container` could be seen as only ever filling one line, and a line won't split. You could try '`block-progression-dimension.maximum="100%" overflow="repeat"`' (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_inline-container and https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#overflow) as the formatter might break an `fo:inline-container` under those conditions.  If you want to really abuse the formatting model, you could put each table row in a separate table in a separate `fo:inline-container`, but only if you're using fixed column widths.  You could try fo:block/fo:inline-container/fo:block-container/fo:table.

Answer (score 0):

@TonyGraham's answer worked for tables. At least for most of my pages. Some tables  still have issues, but I think it can be solved some way. Recommended solution was:

```
fo:block
  fo:basic-link
    fo:inline-container
      fo:table
```

For absolute positioned block-containers I came up with another solution. Just before the block-container I created another same size block-container (also with absolute position) with hyperlink in empty SVG object:

```
<fo:block-container position="absolute" left="6.15cm" top="1.31cm" height="6cm" width="9.32cm" overflow="hidden">
    <fo:block> 
        <fo:basic-link>
            <xsl:attribute name="external-destination">
                <xsl:text>url(</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$my-url"/>
                <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <fo:instream-foreign-object>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="130" width="260" viewBox="0 0 260 130">
                    <text></text>
                </svg>
            </fo:instream-foreign-object>
        </fo:basic-link>
    </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
```

There is some inconvenience in this case. To get SVG viewbox size in points I used Inkscape graphics editor (block-container size in centimiters).